# IIS Throwing HTTP 500 for rewrite rules

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, iis-7.5

When I put my web.config into any folder/main directory it seems to be throwing the HTTP error code: 500--unfortuenly I don't have access to the logs so I can't see why, so surely it's down to my web.config - I've never used IIS before but I'm trying to re-route all requests to a file called 'api.php', here's my web.config file.

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="rule 1Q">
            <match url="^/.*"  />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/api.php" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Apache equivalent:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/.* /api.php
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What version of IIS? and do you have any other service sitting on top of IIS like (example) Tomcat to parse your web files? I know there there is a CGI switch and some isapi settings that may need to be altered to get your rewrite rules to play with IIS. Have you used rewrite rules before on this IIS server? Ruling out errors in construction.

Comment: I'm using version 7.5, rewrite rules work as I've tested them before. Will any PHP errors cause this (just out of interest)? And is my web.config fine?

Comment: I am not sure, but I do know that Isapi and IIS on Coldfusion 10 requires some changes because Tomcat and IIS don't play nice.  That info might be useful to you at least consider other things and get you closer to a solution.  Let me dig up some info and get you another post with some settings to check.

Comment: Appreciate it, thanks Frank!

Comment: Ok, here is one that talks about IIS and Apache specifically, it could gleen starting points.  I'll see if I can find some more specific tips as well. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Installing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cdec18a15-7ffb.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an exact answer because I am not sure of your server variables but here is something that might be useful to you. [Here.](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/importing-apache-modrewrite-rules) This walks through the IIS set up for version 7 and it has some basic concepts. [There is rewrite module/tool that could help](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) but I haven't used it.  [And another document here](http://times.imkrisna.com/2011/03/htaccess-url-rewrite-on-iis-7-5/)...Shows the GUI interface like the first link and is in 7.5.

Again not specific solutions but hopeful you have some server gurus there that can help you at least get the IIS settings right (or at least not sound dumb if you have to communicate something specific to them) if this is a first time IIS Isapi venture for you.

Comment: Frank, I've just tested without the web.config file and everything works fine, although when I put web.config into the directory it gives a 500 HTTP response error--even without anything in the web.config file. Is there a setup for web.config that needs doing--is this common? And it's within the main directory.

Comment: Hi, that wouldn't surprise me that it works fine.  The Isapi rewrite filter.  Have you looked at your Isapi CGI settings? http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/isapicgirestriction also look that this thread... http://forums.iis.net/t/1178302.aspx

Comment: Also when I was fighting around with Isapi a few years back I used a package from these folks here: http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/ and here is some blog discussion comparing two different packages. http://www.helicontech.com/articles/isapi_rewrite3-vs-linkfreeze-which-is-better/ Maybe this would be the better way since you have rewrites built in Apache already.